# How to sort lists within a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have the following dictionary representing data in json format:

```
{'0': {'related_items': [6, 7],
  'values': [0.8111071056538126, 0.8660254037844388]},
 '1': {'related_items': [5, 8],
  'values': [0.9999999999999998, 0.7071067811865475]},
 '222': {'related_items': [], 'values': []},
 '33': {'related_items': [], 'values': []},
 '44': {'related_items': [99], 'values': [0.7071067811865475]},
 '5': {'related_items': [1, 8],
  'values': [0.9999999999999998, 0.7071067811865475]},
 '6': {'related_items': [0, 7, 99],
  'values': [0.8111071056538126, 0.936585811581694, 0.8111071056538126]},
 '7': {'related_items': [0, 6, 99],
  'values': [0.8660254037844388, 0.936585811581694, 0.8660254037844388]},
 '8': {'related_items': [1, 5],
  'values': [0.7071067811865475, 0.7071067811865475]},
 '99': {'related_items': [44, 6, 7],
  'values': [0.7071067811865475, 0.8111071056538126, 0.8660254037844388]}}
```

I want to sort the `related_items` list based on the order of the `values` list (decreasing):
For example for item '0', the lists will be ordered as follows:
{'0': {'related_items': [7, 6],
  'values': [0.8660254037844388,0.8111071056538126]}...

```
for i, j in json_data.items():
    r = j['related_items']
    s = j['values']
    if r:
        sim_final, rel_final = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(s, r),reverse=True)))
        json_data[i]['values']=sim_final
        json_data[i]['related_items']=rel_final
```

The expected output:

```
{'0': {'related_items': [7, 6],
  'values': [0.8660254037844388, 0.8111071056538126]},
 '1': {'related_items': [5, 8],
  'values': [0.9999999999999998, 0.7071067811865475]},
 '222': {'related_items': [], 'values': []},
 '33': {'related_items': [], 'values': []},
 '44': {'related_items': [99], 'values': [0.7071067811865475]},
 '5': {'related_items': [1, 8],
  'values': [0.9999999999999998, 0.7071067811865475]},
 '6': {'related_items': [7, 99, 0],
  'values': [0.936585811581694, 0.8111071056538126, 0.8111071056538126]},
 '7': {'related_items': [6, 99, 0],
  'values': [0.936585811581694, 0.8660254037844388, 0.8660254037844388]},
 '8': {'related_items': [5, 1],
  'values': [0.7071067811865475, 0.7071067811865475]},
 '99': {'related_items': [7, 6, 44],
  'values': [0.8660254037844388, 0.8111071056538126, 0.7071067811865475]}}
```

My actual dict is very large. How can I simplify the `for` loop in the above code?

Comment: Whatever logic you applied is correct, even already simple?

Comment: yes, but my actually dict is very large, it takes lotta time to iterate each items in the dict...

Comment: then use generators to manage load / memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
for k, v in json_data.items():
    x = v["related_items"]
    x.sort(reverse=True)
    y = []
    for i in x:
        y.append(v["values"][v["related_items"].index(i)])
    v["related_items"] = x
    v["values"] = y
```

Not sure if its more elegant, buts its how i would do.

Comment: this sort both 'values' and 'related_items' - this is not i expected - i want to sort the 'values' and using it to reorder the 'related_items'

Comment: missed that bit, i'll delete the answer there

Comment: un-deleted with potentially better option